# What does the 'as' operator do?

Tags: python, methods, operator-keyword

I am learning the basics of Python from Zed Shaw's Learn Python the Hard Way. I am currently at chapter 36 (Symbol review), and came across the 'as' operator. I need to search for it's uses in Python. I know this question is broad, but I didn't found anything as far on python.docs, or SO.
What does this operator do?

Comment: Check out [The `with` Statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted -- looks reasonable to me.  Upvoting to compensate.

Comment: Well, the 'with' statement seems like another use of 'as', so I don't understand the downvote...

Comment: If you're learning from an online course or text, shouldn't the review be based on the material? Isn't the `as` keyword covered somewhere in there?

Comment: No, it says that I should search for it. I have and entire list of operators and functions I need to search and make a program.

Comment: You're learning from material that tells you to look up other material? That seems a little odd.

Comment: @JohnLockwood - please don't [use your vote just to cancel out someone else's vote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253383/upvotes-that-cancel-out-downvotes).

Comment: It's used in various [simple](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html) and [compound](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html) statements.

Comment: To be clear, it's not an operator at all. It's just a keyword that can be used in two distinct statements, an `import` statement and a `with` statement.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: You can vote [however you like](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209849/to-what-extent-i-am-free-with-my-voting).

Comment: @Kevin - absolutely, but I can also encourage people to follow whatever commonly-accepted voting practices I like. :)

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for that.  That was pretty much always the plan. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is used to create an alias when importing modules or when using the `with` clause:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

#####

with open(file_name, 'r') as my_file:
    my_file.readlines()
```

Answer (score 2):

Its used with the `with` keyword:

```
with open("file.foo") as f:
    # Do something with f
    pass
```